# Qty for Item's Status to Become Out of Stock - Problem with mass upload

Tags: inventory, out-of-stock

I am using a php script which works great with updating stock but when a simple product is 1 or below stock availability isn't changing to "out of stock". I have "Qty for Item's Status to Become Out of Stock" at 2. I have to go into the product and click save then it will change to out of stock.

This there faster way or am i missing something easy? code below

```
    <?php
/**
 * @author      MagePsycho <info@magepsycho.com>
 * @website     http://www.magepsycho.com
 * @category    Export / Import
 */
$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
umask(0);
Mage::app('admin');
Mage::register('isSecureArea', 1);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit','1024M');

/***************** UTILITY FUNCTIONS ********************/
function _getConnection($type = 'core_read'){
    return Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection($type);
}

function _getTableName($tableName){
    return Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName($tableName);
}

function _getAttributeId($attribute_code = 'price'){
    $connection = _getConnection('core_read');
    $sql = "SELECT attribute_id
                FROM " . _getTableName('eav_attribute') . "
            WHERE
                entity_type_id = ?
                AND attribute_code = ?";
    $entity_type_id = _getEntityTypeId();
    return $connection->fetchOne($sql, array($entity_type_id, $attribute_code));
}

function _getEntityTypeId($entity_type_code = 'catalog_product'){
    $connection = _getConnection('core_read');
    $sql        = "SELECT entity_type_id FROM " . _getTableName('eav_entity_type') . " WHERE entity_type_code = ?";
    return $connection->fetchOne($sql, array($entity_type_code));
}

function _checkIfSkuExists($sku){
    $connection = _getConnection('core_read');
    $sql        = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_no FROM " . _getTableName('catalog_product_entity') . " WHERE sku = ?";
    $count      = $connection->fetchOne($sql, array($sku));
    if($count > 0){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

function _getIdFromSku($sku){
    $connection = _getConnection('core_read');
    $sql        = "SELECT entity_id FROM " . _getTableName('catalog_product_entity') . " WHERE sku = ?";
    return $connection->fetchOne($sql, array($sku));
}

function _updateStocks($data){
    $connection     = _getConnection('core_write');
    $sku            = $data[0];
    $newQty         = $data[1];
    $productId      = _getIdFromSku($sku);
    $attributeId    = _getAttributeId();

    $sql            = "UPDATE " . _getTableName('cataloginventory_stock_item') . " csi,
                       " . _getTableName('cataloginventory_stock_status') . " css
                       SET
                       csi.qty = ?,
                       csi.is_in_stock = ?,
                       css.qty = ?,
                       css.stock_status = ?
                       WHERE
                       csi.product_id = ?
                       AND csi.product_id = css.product_id";
    $isInStock      = $newQty > 0 ? 1 : 0;
    $stockStatus    = $newQty > 0 ? 1 : 0;
    $connection->query($sql, array($newQty, $isInStock, $newQty, $stockStatus, $productId));
}
/***************** UTILITY FUNCTIONS ********************/

$csv                = new Varien_File_Csv();
$data               = $csv->getData('stocks.csv'); //path to csv
array_shift($data);

$message = '';
$count   = 1;
foreach($data as $_data){
    if(_checkIfSkuExists($_data[0])){
        try{
            _updateStocks($_data);
            $message .= $count . '> Success:: Qty (' . $_data[1] . ') of Sku (' . $_data[0] . ') has been updated. <br />';

        }catch(Exception $e){
            $message .=  $count .'> Error:: while Upating  Qty (' . $_data[1] . ') of Sku (' . $_data[0] . ') => '.$e->getMessage().'<br />';
        }
    }else{
        $message .=  $count .'> Error:: Product with Sku (' . $_data[0] . ') does\'t exist.<br />';
    }
    $count++;
}
echo $message;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your if statement would override your stock settings.

$isInStock      = $newQty > 0 ? 1 : 0;

$stockStatus    = $newQty > 0 ? 1 : 0;

so it would only set stock to out o' stock if stock == 0. then as you said you need to go into the admin and save the item to trigger your stock rules.

if you reindex your data base after running this script it could possibly correct your stock issue?

otherwise set you if statement to

$isInStock      = $newQty <= 2 ? 0 : 1;

$stockStatus    = $newQty <= 2 ? 0 : 1;